# Getting compilation errors when trying to create function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using below code to remove '-' symbol in phone attribute

```
drop function funphone

create function funphone
declare @phone varchar(20)
return  
is 
@retphone varchar(20)
begin 
      select phone from src_emp where phone=@phone
      @retphone=replace(replace(@phone,'-',''),'-','')
      return @retphone
end
```

but I'm getting Warning: Function created with compilation errors

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please help

Comment: It looks like you're using SQL Developer IDE. In which case you should read this blog post by @thatjeffsmith on [reading PL/SQL compilation errors](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/viewing-plsql-compilation-errors-in-oracle-sql-developer/)

Comment: Oh, and as you appear to be trying to use SQL Server syntax in Oracle you should probably read [the PL/SQL Language Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged Oracle but the code looks like SQL Server.  In Oracle, I would expect something more like this:

```
create function funphone (
    in_phone in varchar2
)
return varchar2
as 
    v_retphone varchar2(20);
begin 
    select replace(e.phone, '-', '') into v_retphone
    from src_emp e
    where e.phone = in_phone;

    return v_retphone;
end ;
```

Comment: I assume Gordon needs a rest, he forgot all the semicolons.